# Some Group Policy defined inbound exceptions not showing on local machine

Tags: windows, firewall

I am turning on the Windows Firewall for the first time for my domain. I am only worrying about workstations for now, and I have defined a list of inbound exceptions. I have these set up using environment variables, since a lot of people have things installed in various locations (devs install their own environments how they want) to point to each person's install locations. So, for example, if someone is running Tomcat on their machine with other people connecting, they will just need to create an environment variable that points to their install, and it should get the exception from the policy. This has worked really well in my testing for the most part.

I am having a few people help me test the policy before implementing it. For the most part, it works really well, and the Tomcat exceptions work fine. However, at least one person is not having a certain program show up in their local exception list. They have the correct variable set up, and have run multiple gpupdates and rebooted their machine. On another test machine, I couldn't get the exception to show up until a reboot. It works fine on one machine, and doesn't show up on another. Both have the program installed and the environment variable created correctly. The exception shows up when I run rsop.msc on their computer and look through the inbound exception list, but it won't show up in Control Panel > Firewall > Allow a Program or Feature through...

It was working fine on that machine at first, but now it refuses to list the new exceptions.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Edit: Just to clarify - the machine is clearly getting the policy, as I can see the rules set when I open up rsop.msc, or when I run the Group Policy Results wizard from the DC. The only place they are not taking effect is in the Firewall inbound exceptions list on the local computer, and therefore they are not allowing the proper programs through. It's really strange because one executable in that folder, using the same environment variable shows up, but not another. It also works fine on another computer I've tested it on.

Comment: Can you add some actual details about *how* you're doing all this?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. The inbound exceptions are set up in Computer Configuration > Admin Templates > Network > Network Connections > Windows Firewall > Domain Profile > Define Inbound Program Exceptions.
The exception rules point to installs using an environment variable such as "%Tomcat_Home%" so that each user just has to set up that variable pointing to their install location.

Comment: I haven't used those settings in a long time.  Is there a reason you are using the ADM template for firewall settings instead of "GPO\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Windows Firewall with Advanced Security"?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this before.

I fixed it the hard way.

There was a problem with the NIC driver binding to the IP stack.

I booted the system without a NIC.
Installed a loopback adapter.
Set an IP to the adapter.
Configured and it worked.
I then installed an Intel NIC (the NIC I was using was not very desirable, won't name manufacturer)
and everything was fine.

The easy way.

Use the NetShell utility to reset the IP stack.

netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
You can look at the log to see the output in the txt file
Here is the article
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways